# Can't output JSON Data from external file with an object

Tags: php, json, decode

My problem with JSON & PHP:
I try to show the JSON values on my website:

**JSON Content**

```
{
  "promisArticle": [
    {
      "tradeItem": [
        {
          "hierarchyTradeItemGtin": [
            {
              "value": "04008400304014",
              "quantity": 40
            }
          ],
          "identification": {
            "productGroupConditionDe": "0816",
            "gpcCategory": "10000045",
            "isTradeItemABaseUnit": "true",
            "isTradeItemAConsumerUnit": "true",
            "isTradeItemADespatchUnit": "false",
            "isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit": "true",
            "isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit": "true",
            "unitDescriptor": "BASE_UNIT_OR_EACH",
            "dangerousGoodsRegulation": "ZNA",
            "effectiveDate": "2019-10-08T22:00:00Z",
            "startAvailabilityDate": "2011-12-26T23:00:00Z",
            "lastChangeDate": "2019-10-08T22:00:00Z",
            "biocideRegulationCode": "NOT_APPLICABLE",
            "quantityOfBaseUnits": 1,
            "zasVersion": "ZAS7",
            "baseUnitGtin": "00000040084015"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON Code is valid.

**PHP Code**

```
$filename = 'https://urltojson.json'
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = json_decode($content);

foreach($data->promisArticle as $promisArticle)
{
echo 'My Output:' .$promisArticle->tradeItem->identification->baseUnitGtin .' !';   
}
```

**Result:**

```
My Output: !
```

When i use `print_r($data);` then i get this:

```
stdClass Object ( [promisArticle] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tradeItem] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [hierarchyTradeItemGtin] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [value] => 04008400304014 [quantity] => 40 ) ) [identification] => stdClass Object ( [productGroupConditionDe] => 0816 [gpcCategory] => 10000045 [isTradeItemABaseUnit] => true [isTradeItemAConsumerUnit] => true [isTradeItemADespatchUnit] => false [isTradeItemAnInvoiceUnit] => true [isTradeItemAnOrderableUnit] => true [unitDescriptor] => BASE_UNIT_OR_EACH [dangerousGoodsRegulation] => ZNA [effectiveDate] => 2019-10-08T22:00:00Z
[...]
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/SUfA4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function json_decode on PHP has some parameters, the second parameters indicates to return an array instead an object, and you are accessing your data as object (the -> operator), so you need indicate false on second parameter

```
$data = json_decode($content, false);
```

[PHP manual json_decode function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)